# Mudar idioma do site

Tags: php

Estou com problema nos idiomas do site, ele possui 4 idiomas e quando se clica nos outros idiomas há momentos que ele troca e na maioria das vezes ele não troca, não sei se está guardado as informações no cache. Não fui eu quem desenvolvi o site então fica um pouco mais complicado para passar aqui, caso alguma informação falte me diga que eu procuro.

Aqui está o mapeamento das línguas

```
<map name="MapIdioma">
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,2,19,19" href="index.php?idioma=portugues">
            <area shape="rect" coords="24,2,43,18" href="index.php?idioma=english">
            <area shape="rect" coords="46,2,66,19" href="index.php?idioma=espanol">
            <area shape="rect" coords="69,2,89,17" href="index.php?idioma=alemao">
</map>
```

E aqui são as sessões que começam

```
if ($_REQUEST['idioma'] == 'portugues')
{
    $_SESSION['idIdioma']   = '1';
    /*header ("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);*/
    echo "<script>document.location='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'</script>";
    exit();
}

if ($_REQUEST['idioma'] == 'english')
{
    $_SESSION['idIdioma']   = '2';
    /*header ("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);*/
    echo "<script>document.location='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'</script>";
    exit();
}

if ($_REQUEST['idioma'] == 'espanol')
{
    $_SESSION['idIdioma']   = '3';
    /*header ("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);*/
    echo "<script>document.location='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'</script>";
    exit();
}

if ($_REQUEST['idioma'] == 'alemao')
{
    $_SESSION['idIdioma']   = '4';
    /*header ("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);*/
    echo "<script>document.location='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'</script>";
    exit();
}

if (!session_is_registered('idIdioma'))
    $_SESSION['idIdioma'] = '1';

if ($_SESSION['idIdioma'] != '1' and $_SESSION['idIdioma'] != '2' and $_SESSION['idIdioma'] != '3' and $_SESSION['idIdioma'] != '4')
    $_SESSION['idIdioma'] = '1';

if ($_SESSION['idIdioma'] == '1')
    include 'idioma.portugues.php';

if ($_SESSION['idIdioma'] == '2')
    include 'idioma.ingles.php';

if ($_SESSION['idIdioma'] == '3')
    include 'idioma.espanhol.php';

if ($_SESSION['idIdioma'] == '4')
    include 'idioma.alemao.php';
?>
```

Comment: Em off: `english`, `espanol`, `alemao`, `portugues`? Estabeleça um padrão para nomes de idiomas. Sugestão: `english`, `espanol`, `deutsch`, `portugues`.

Comment: Algum motivo para o idIdioma ser uma string e não um inteiro?  Já agora, depender demasiado do HTTP_REFERER é problemático. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934747/is-serverhttp-referer-safe (link em inglês, as primeiras duas respostas têm interesse)

Answer (score 2):

Não consegui identificar o problema, pode ser algo fora do escopo do script que nos passou, porém, tornei a liberdade de reescrever seu script.

https://gist.github.com/juniorb2ss/a3db0d9b0fab03406a89

```
$arrayIdiomas = array('portugues' => 'idioma.portugues.php', 'english' =>    'idioma.ingles.php', 'espanol' => 'idioma.espanhol.php', 'alemao' => 'idioma.alemao.php');

// Definindo o idioma padrão
if(!isset($_SESSION['idIdioma'])){
   $_SESSION['idIdioma'] = 'portugues';
}


 if(isset($_REQUEST['idioma'])){
 // o idioma seleciona existe?
  if(array_key_exists($_REQUEST['idioma'], $arrayIdiomas)){
    $_SESSION['idIdioma'] = $_REQUEST['idioma']; // seta o idioma selecionado
    echo "<script>document.location=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']</script>"; // refresh na página
    exit();
 }
}
else{
 // idioma definido na sessão é valido?
 if(array_key_exists($_SESSION['idIdioma'], $arrayIdiomas)){
    include $arrayIdiomas [$_SESSION['idIdioma']]; // inclue o arquivo.
 }
}
```

Não testei, porém acredito que esta funcionando, nesta forma ficará mais legível o seu código.

Comment: No `document.location` ele deixou de ser uma string. E talvez fosse melhor fazer algum tipo de verificação do HTTP_REFERER, para o caso de ter sido interceptado (por um ataque Man-in-the-middle, por exemplo)

Comment: O melhor é enviar para uma url pré-definida.